# Dual monitor on laptop

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a Dell( Inspiron R17 N7110) laptop with both outputs VGA and HDMI and I have already a samsung monitor that supports only VGA,  any way I want to buy another monitor which supports HDMI, my question is can will I have a dual extended monitors !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most laptops will allow you to extend the desktop to another monitor giving you dual displays, but don't give you functionality to extend over 2 external monitors and the internal laptop monitor.

so it is really one or the other.

---

I found another question that was similar to yours and the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/230595/162960) on it really hammers out efficiently what your options are, the comments follow up.

the answer pretty much says that you can purchase a USB adapter to connect another screen and that it should allow you to use more than one external monitor,  if you need all three screens this is something that you might want to try out.  the answer was meant for someone only wanting to use the two external monitors though.

Comment: i realy don't need my laptop display I only need the monitors !

Comment: it did work even with two monitors + the laptop monitor so i have three displays !

Comment: Very nice glad this worked for you

Comment: someone jalous maybe

Answer (score 0):

This generally always depends on the card in your computer. It's most common for VGA to route the same as HDMI. Meaning no, it would not be possible. Most cards cannot output analog (VGA) and digital (HDMI/DVI) at the same time.

I briefly reviewed the specs of the computer specified and do not believe it is possible. I would also strongly reccomend using a desktop for dual monitor purposes.

Comment: I have two graphic cards , intel HD & nvidea

Comment: @BadikAli I do not believe it will work. Sorry.

Comment: am sorry but it did work (laptop + two monitors)